# 'Must contain specific value' on ActiveAdmin field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to test my models on ActiveAdmin by creating them manually. On one of my model, a field says 'Must contain specific value' whatever i write in it. This attribute can only contain a value from a list which is predefined. I suppose this field should not be a text field but a combobox filed with the values of this list. I looked for it on Google but can't find the answer.what I have tried upto is bellow

```
f.input :modele, :as => :select, :collection => proc{current_route.modele.all}
```

but it doesn't work and worse I don't understand what I'm doing.

Comment: try this,  f.input :modele, :as => :select, :collection => current_route.modele.all.map{|m| [m.value, m.id]}

Comment: It returns me this error : `undefined local variable or method 'current_route' `

Comment: Where is this list of allowed values defined?

Comment: In my Route model : `def planifie
    case self.modele
      when 'route.unique' then return
      when 'route.allerretour' then planifie_allerretour
      when 'route.regulier' then planifie_regulier
    end
  end`